# creating a Custom Dialog with DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I've found several supposedly working examples, each is little bit different from the other, but whichever I tried to implement I get the same compiler error. Here's code for the `DialogFragment`. No problem reported here.

**EDIT:** I actually had coded **Custom**DialogFragment in my code after I had posted. That WOULD be a problem, but it actually wasn't. I apologize.

`public class` **Custom**`DialogFragment extends DialogFragment`

```
    {
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog, container, false);
            getDialog().setTitle("dialog");
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

I've made `btn` `static`. No difference. I've moved the code out of `onClick` into `onCreate`. No difference. Made my activity extend `FragmentActivity`. No matter what I do, I get this error on the line with ****** below:

`cannot resolve method 'show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)'`

code for the `Activity`:

```
public class CustomDialogActivity extends Activity
{
  Button btn ;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog);
    btn = new Button(this);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        CustomDialogFragment dialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment"); // **********     
      }
    });
  }
}
```

What should I do? Most of the code comes from one web page or another or the other. You'd think I could get it to run.

If I remove `Custom` from both sides of the statement above the ******, it compiles,  but then it's not MY `CustomDialog` anymore and no dialog shows anyway. (If I remove `Custom` from just one side, I get compiler error. Casting fails.)

If I use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in place of `fm` in the line with ******, there's no error, but no dialog pops up.

I'm obviously lost.

---

P.S. Here's `build.gradle` for `app`; `xml` follows, but surely it's not the problem:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dslomer64.customdialogactivity"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

simple_dialog_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dismiss" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have created a class called as MyDialogFragment and nit customDialogFragment therefore use MyDialogFragment.

Comment: Good point @shubhamgarg1, but as my EDIT indicates, the code I was working on actually had class named CUSTOMDialogFragment, not MYDialogFragment. So, yes, you are absolutely right about wrong class name, but that wasn't the problem I was having. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I did what I should have done long ago: read completely through and took notes on "everything" there is to know about [Dialog coding, with great examples](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) and looked for tips and took notes at [Dialog design do's and dont's](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html), where there's also a lot of info about Theming at the end. *Questions about* `Dialog`? Go there.

Only 3 lines of executable `DialogFragment` statements is a bit lean. For one thing, it had no overridden `onCreateDialog` method. And putting `onClick` in the `Activity` wasn't a good idea since it referred to a Fragment that hadn't even been created and since the action takes place in the `Fragment`.

And as @Commonsware pointed out, I should have been using the Support Library versions of `Activity` and `Fragment`.

So, here's what the activity should have been:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog);
    CustomDialogFragment cdf = new CustomDialogFragment();
    cdf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Showing dialog");
  }
}
```

And here's the dialog fragment. I wish I could say it's all my code, but I got it all from one example or other at the first link above. But sometimes it's just what ya do:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

...

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
{
  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog, container,false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Simple Dialog");
    return rootView;
  }

  @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Simple Dialog");
    builder.setMessage("Hey, a dialog!");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.fire, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dismiss();
      }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.cancel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dismiss();
      }
    });
    return builder.create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your fragment is named `MyDialogFragment`. You are trying to show `CustomDialogFragment`. Those are not the same. From the code snippets in your question, it would appear that you have nothing named `CustomDialogFragment`.

Once you fix that, you need to ensure that you are using the same fragment system consistently. Given that native fragments are deprecated in Android 9.0+, for new development, you should be using a library edition of fragments. That would involve:

- Having your activity extend from `FragmentActivity` or from something else that extends `FragmentActivity`, such as `AppCompatActivity`
- Having your fragment extend from `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`
- Using `getSupportFragmentManager()`

(note: I am using Android Support Library package names in this answer — substitute with `androidx` editions if you are using AndroidX)

Comment: Ah, man... yes... but ... as my edit and comment shows, my code in AS at time of submission did not have the error of class name and object name not matching. I changed DialogFragment name because any object that starts with "My" just seems a little childish.

So that was not the problem I was having. 

Maybe I should submit the question in a new thread after implementing your suggestions, assuming I have the same problem.. 

Maybe I should delete this question since as of now it's just silly. 

Dare I ask for another look with the edited correct class definition?

Comment: @DSlomer64: It is likely that the "I get this error on the line" issue is that you have a mismatched set of fragment implementations. Everything after that is very murky in your question, and we have no code for that anyway. I cannot tell you whether to delete the question. My only suggestion is that if you do ask a fresh question, that you provide complete unedited source, where "complete" includes the `import` statements. This may require you to create a scrap project where you reproduce the problem... and if you cannot reproduce it there, that gives you an avenue for fixing the problem.